# Laravel access to column object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table, table name is bookings and here have a column e_provider. this column i direct fetch data by id and save all data in e_provider field
how can i access this e_provider data like $data->e_provider->name

here is code

```
    [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "e_provider": "{"id":11,"name":"Architect O'Reilly, Ratke and Miller","phone_number":"661.425.3559","mobile_number":"307.607.7472"}",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in laravel 8 and less try this

Defining A Accessors & Mutators

```
public function getEProviderAttribute(){
     return json_decode($this->getAttributeValue('e_provider'));
}

public function setEProviderAttribute($value){
     return json_encode($value);
}
```

For update value

```
$e_provider = $object->e_provider;
$e_provider->name = "new name";
$object->e_provider = $e_provider;
$object->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Any solutin for update this field ?

Comment: answer updated @md-masum

Answer (score 1):

You can use $casts in your model

```
class BookingModel extends Model

    {
        protected $casts = [
            'e_provider' => AsCollection::class,
        ];
    }
```

Now you will be able to get the data by the following:

```
$bookingModel->e_provider->id
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-object-and-collection-casting

Another way if you don't want to use casts, you can define an accessor:

```
    protected function eProvider(): Attribute
        {
            return Attribute::make(
                get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value),
                set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
            );
        }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Any solutin for update this field ?